# new in ubuntu but having issues while trying to install drivers and i dont know what to do

Tags: drivers, partitioning, kernel

before i start i have to repeat, im new in ubuntu and everything that comes with it:C i (im using version 20,04)i just formatted my pc from windows 10 to ubuntu yesterday, i know the bare minimum and im starting to realize that linux might be for specialized users since i didnt even know that there was a command/terminal app and that i need to use it for a lot of things! nonetheless im eager to learn

now to the issue! i was reading through forums or questions here in askubuntu about the necessary drivers to either play games or do other stuff and how to do it,everything was going great until i installed vulkan or maybe was something before but i dont know for sure, then my pc crashed and when i restarted this happened

"Error Kernel panic – not syncing: VFS : Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block"
and the blackscreen of death!!
there are a lots of answers regarding this issue i know but like i said im a total noob in this i just cant understand the answers and how to applied them correctly without making a mess, i saw one answer that seemed pretty complete regarding the issue but he says to be careful while deleting some stuff or we are in trouble, same with other answers that talked about removing kernel, im afraid to do something stupid unaware
now although I would appreciate an answer like "how to 101 to stupid people", i know i need to start learning about this, but is it worth the trouble? it seems that i need to learn a LOT and i barely have 3 or 4 free hours in my day or maybe weekends ;c
does things like this happen a lot in ubuntu?(once in a week, in a month?) or is it just my bad luck? while im eager to learn i dont wanna waste my free time fixing issues all the time.
before this while installing drivers the same happened and since i didn't had a lot of things in the pc i choose to just formatted ubuntu again but now seeing that the same happens with different drivers im not so sure anymore about ubuntu
pd:sorry if grammar mistakes,english is not my native language

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that, 20.04

Comment: Linux is usually more reliable and secure than Windows. Setting it up for gaming can become complicated so I would recommend you install an application called TimeShift. With that if you run it just before making system changes you can roll back to the previous working state. I’d say it’s worth the effort especially if you enjoy learning about computers

Comment: Thats one useful application! it will save me a lot of time in the future in case of screw ups, I appreciate that

Comment: If you make a mess, so what? You obviously have an install media. Learn from your mistakes, then reinstall if necessary. Eventually you will learn alternatives to reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

About your doubts on switching to Ubuntu, it's totally normal if you're new to GNU/Linux to make such a mistake, you will gain experience with continuative use and in some cases through trail and error. From personal experience, I've learned to make sure to run programs (and most of all commands from terminal) only as long as I understand the reason behind and I feel confident I can regress to previous state. If you have the patience to go through the process of learning from the ground up how your system works you will have great satisfaction in becoming more and more aware of what goes on under the hood when you do your computing, and in the end you'll be able to fix almost all unexpected issues that you may face. Firstable it's essential to familiarize with the concept of distro branch, package manager, desktop environment, window manager. Thankfully there's a whole lot of useful resources on the internet, much many than before (I've definitely switched to GNU/Linux about 10 yrs ago). With that said, I hope you won't get discouraged and give up because as you get used to the new OS you realise more easily what went wrong and avoid making the same mistakes. Distributions with great support base like Ubuntu are the perfect point to start from if you are a beginner coming from proprietary OS such as MS win10, finally I think it's worth it since open source and free software is just that much more powerful and fun to tinker with and gives you greater freedom and choice

Comment: you know what?you were right although it wasn't much but when i finally solved the problem now it did feel great, it seems that i have a long road ahead but it seems fun c: